# Getting a sentence from spesific number from the text file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I work on Visual Studio about Python Project.
I change hexadecimal number to the binary like that:

```
print("Enter a hex for converting binary");
hexdec = input("Enter any number in Hexadecimal form: ");
bin_value = bin(int(hexdec,16))[2:]
bin_value = (8 - (len(bin_value)% 8)) * '0' + bin_value
bytes = [bin_value[i:i+8] for i in range(0, len(bin_value), 8)]
' '.join(bytes)
print(' '.join(bytes));
```

So, the output look like that:

```
00000001
```

I want to use the binary number from the up and read a file line by line and take the result of sentence from this text file:

```
00000110 Address complete
00001001 Answer
01000001 Application transport
00000001 Blocking 39
```

So, the expected output only be look like:

```
Blocking 39
```

Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Unfortunately, questions like these are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) because they address mostly the business logic instead of isolated programming issues. In case you have issues with the implementation of your system, try split your problem into [minimal, complete, and verifiable questions about programming issues](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes there are ways to do that. The first part of your question showing how you get the binary representation is un-needed. In fact it's irrelevant to the question. You want to know how to find a line in a file beginning with a particular string, and split it to get the rest of the line. See how to create a [mcve]. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will be carefull about that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
key = "00000001"

with open("data.txt") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line.startswith(key):
            print(line.lstrip(key + " "))
```

Comment: This will not work if the sentence on the right contains the key. It will also not work if the sentence starts with `0` or `1`.

Comment: Thank you @Lutz Horn but I take the data from messagetype.txt looks like : with open('messagetype.txt', 'r') as f: how to take data from this file?

Comment: okay it helps me a lot thank you so much for that, one more thing, I want to use "bytes" which I take the input from the user for the key, but it tells me this is not string. starswith doesn't accept this bytes, is there any way to use bytes in your code? @Lutz Horn

Comment: Awe I did it I see key = ' '.join(bytes) for taking input and it totally works thank you a lot @Lutz Horn you safe my life thank you thank you thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the binary number is stored in variable `key` and your lookup file is opened as file object `f`:

```
open('messagetype.txt', 'r') as f:
    for l in f:
        k, v = l.split(maxsplit=1)
        if k == key:
            print(v)
```

Given your sample input, this will output:

```
Blocking 39
```

Comment: Thank you so much @blhsing but I use with open('messagetype.txt', 'r') as f: for taking data, how to take from this one ?

Comment: Thank you @blhsing it helps me alot but one more thing, I want to use bytes like you see in my code  " I take the input hex and convert to binary" how can I use bytes in your code

Comment: Awe, I did it thank you thank you thank you so much @blhsing you safe my life :)

Comment: Yes, I gave it also in the future I'l give you up for this help :)